# Apache - create multiple aliases

Tags: server, 14.04, apache2

I'm trying to setup two websites on my Apache server.  One is www.domain.com and the other is test.domain.com.  Currently, my 000-default.conf file reads as follows:

> `<VirtualHost www:80>
>         # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
>         # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
>         # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
>         # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
>         # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
>         # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
>         # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
>         #ServerName www.domain.com
>         #ServerAlias www
>         ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
>         DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
>         # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
>         # error, crit, alert, emerg.
>         # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
>         # modules, e.g.
>         #LogLevel info ssl:warn
>         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.error.log
>         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.access.log combined
>         UseCanonicalName on
>         
>         allow from all
>         Options +Indexes
>         
>         # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
>         # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
>         # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
>         # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
>         # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
>         #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
> </VirtualHost>
> <VirtualHost test:80>
>         DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain.com/test/"
>         ServerName test.domain.com
>         ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
>         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.domain.error.log
>         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.domain.access.log combined
>         UseCanonicalName on
>         
>         allow from all
>         Options +Indexes
>         
> </VirtualHost>
> # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet`

As is, when I use a browser to go to the www location, it show me a directory listing.  However, if I remove the www:80 on Line 1 and replace it with *:80, it correctly displays the webpage.  I don't understand why.

Can anyone help me configure this 000-default.conf file so that www goes to "/var/www/domain.com" and that test goes to "/var/www/domain.com/test"?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the [`VirtualHost` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) is

```
<VirtualHost addr[:port] [addr[:port]] ...> ... </VirtualHost>
```

Where `addr` is the address of the virtual host, not its physical path.

So it is safer to use an IP (or the `*` wildcard). It even says it in the documentation that, you can use a **fully qualified** domain, but it is not recommended:

From the documentation:

> A fully qualified domain name for the IP address of the virtual host (not recommended)

To achieve what you are asking, you need a combination of the `DocumentRoot` and `ServerName` directives. Which, in fact, are already there.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/
    ServerName www.domain.com
    # Some other configs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/test/
    ServerName test.domain.com
    # Some other configs
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Also, there is another issue in your virtual host configuration, as of apache2.4 (which is shipped by default in 14.04) the `allow` directive is replaced with the `Require` directive.

It also needs be inside a special directive, for example, the `Directory` directive:

```
<Directory "/var/www/domain.com/">
    Require all granted
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

This is a complete Virtual Host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.access.log combined
    UseCanonicalName on

    <Directory "/var/www/domain.com/">
        Require all granted
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was exactly what I needed.  It's now working the way I want it to.